# What software for cloud motion forecasting

Tags: meteorology, clouds, weather-forecasting, software

I have a large sequence of images in .png (10 second resolution) from sky image system. Is there any inexpensive software for processing images and forecasting cloud motion?

I have found out that several universities are developing it, but i don't have access to them.

Comment: Did you need the software for a non-commercial/scientific purpose or for a commercial one? In the first case: did you contact the respective institutions?

Comment: Non-comercial purpose. It is research project financed from government.